# Functions of a random vector

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, density-function

following question: I don't know how the hell happened to the double integral in the proof below and how the r appeared behind the 1/pi. I would really appreciate  your help on this.

[image]

Best, KingDingeling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say

$\iint_A f(x,y)\,dxdy=\int_0^a\int_0^b g(r,\Theta)|J|\,drd\Theta$.

J = Jacobian of transformation to polar coordinates = r.